# Polymorphism in Java with Services

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I am new to object-oriented programming. I want to create Email Body based on the EnumType I receive from the request from the UI.

For example, if I receive Enum value A, I need to build an email body with some attributes which I receive from a database and other services.
I need different behavior if the Enum value is different.

I tried to Create

```java
public interface EmailService {
  String getBody();
  String getStatus();
}

public class AEmailService implements EmailService {
  Service X;
  DAOService Y;

   .... Some operations.

}

public class BEmailService implements EmailService {
  Service X;
  DAOService Y;
   .... Some operations.

}
```

Now, how can I use the EmailService interface and replace it with the objects of AEmailService or BEmailService on runtime based on the enum value in the request.

Is it better to do to perform this?

Answer (score 2):

You could parametrize your `enum` with a `Supplier<EmailService>`, e.g.:

```
public enum EmailServiceTypes {

    A(AEmailService::new),
    B(BEmailService::new);//etc

    private Supplier<EmailService> supplier;
    EmailServiceTypes(Supplier<EmailService> supplier) {
        this.supplier = supplier;
    }

    public EmailService supply() {
        return supplier.get();
    }
}
```

Based on the enum value you're getting as an input, you just need to invoke `get` and you'll get the desired instance.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do it, with an if-else condition:

```
EmailService mEmailService;
if (receivedEnum == EnumType.WHATEVER) {
    mEmailService = new AEmailService();
} else {
    mEmailService = new BEmailService();
}
```

Basically you want an object of the interface type, and you instantiate it with a concrete implementation of that interface depending of whatever you want.

I edit to add the possibility to encapsulate even more the previous behavior with the FactoryPattern:

```
public class EmailServiceFactory {

    public static EmailService getEmailService(EmailEnum enum) {
        switch (enum) {
            case EMAIL_TYPE_A:
                return new AEmailService();
            case EMAIL_TYPE_B:
                return new BEmailService();
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

   EmailService mEmailService = EmailServiceFactory.getEmailService(EMAIL_TYPE_A);
   mEmailService.getBody(); // This will call getBody() from AEmailService class

   mEmailService = EmailServiceFactory.getEmailService(EMAIL_TYPE_B);
   mEmailService.getBody(); // This will call getBody() from BEmailService class

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question, something like:

```
EmailService emailSrvc;
switch (myEnum) {
  case AEMAIL:
    emailSrvc = new AEmailService();
    break;
  case BEMAIL:
     emailSrvc = new BEmailService();
     break;

}

String body emailSrvc.getBody();

...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try Strategy pattern

```
inteface EmailStrategy {
}
```

Define different strategies

```
StrategyA implements EmailStrategy{ some actions}
StrategyB implements EmailStrategy{ some actions}
```

Your EmailService can be concrete class and will contain EmailStrategyInterface

```
class EmailService{
EmailStrategy strategy;
}
```

When you will receive enum value you can simply set matching strategy to this field and call action methods